# How can I adjust the seekbar placed at the end?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Usually when an android app run the seekbar placed at the start. 
I want to when my app run the seekbar placed at the end, not in the start.
How can I do this?
Thank you.
Ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mSeekBar.setProgress(mSeekBar.getMax());
```